# What happens if CImage::Load method fails?

Tags: c++, api, mfc, atl

Will a [CImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5.aspx)'s pixels be changed if it attempts to load another image, and the load method fails ?

Comment: Did you try it out already?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Testing for failure is not as easy as you make it sound. Loading can fail for a number of reasons: The image file may not be present, the file may be inaccessible from the current user, the image file may have an unsupported or invalid file format, the application runs out of memory, and so on. Some of those error conditions will not destroy a previously loaded image, while others will.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I tried , it failed and the pixels remain unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception guarantees are not documented, so you cannot assume anything.

Looking at the source code for `CImage::Load` (*atlimage.h*) reveals, that failure to load an image can destroy the previously stored image. Both `Load` overloads eventually call into `CImage::CreateFromGdiplusBitmap`. This class member performs two operations: 1.) It calls `Create` to create new storage for the image. This operation is destructive. 2.) It copies the source image data into the destination. This operation can fail.

Since you have an operation that can fail following the operation that destroys any previous data, you cannot assume that failure to load an image will retain the previous image data.

The following code implements non-destructive image loading, by first loading an image into a temporary, and assigning it to the destination on success only:

```
HRESULT NonDestructiveLoad( CImage& img, const CString& fileName ) {
    CImage tempImage;
    HRESULT hr = tempImage.Load( fileName );
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
        // The following operations cannot fail
        img.Destroy();
        img.Attach( tempImage.Detach() );
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ,this is exactly what I need .

Comment: Also, you can use `CImage::IsNull()` to check if loading was successful at a different point in the code.